# How can I write a gzip byte array to disk with log4j2?

Tags: java, log4j, gzip, log4j2

I have a string that I want to log with log4j2. I first want to compress that string then write the resulting bytes to the log file. So the code looks something like this

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(baos);
gzip.write(myLogString.getBytes());
gzip.close();
log.info(baos.toByteArray());
```

Unfortunately it looks like log4j at some point converts the byte array to a string which results in a file that's not in GZIP format. Is there any way to accomplish what I'm after?

Comment: I would not try to write raw bytes to a log file. Either Base64 encode the data, or write it to a separate file with a generated name, and log the file name.

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to do this?

Comment: @aled I'd like the log files to be in .gz and would like to generate these log files by compressing each log message and appending that compressed message to the file

Comment: @tgdavies unfortunately that's not an option. the question is whether this is possible through log4j or whether it'll have to be implemented independently

Comment: `baos` doesn't contain a valid gzipped file until you've closed `gzip`. Why exactly are you trying to do this?

Comment: the code snippet was just for illustration. i've edited it now to close the gzip stream.

Comment: You need to explain what you are trying to achieve, and why you are considering using log4j to do it.

Comment: In your code you decide **what** to log, then you decide **how** to do it in your configuration file (e.g. rotate logs daily and gzip the old ones).

Comment: @tgdavies I want to create gzipped log files by compressing the message at the time it's written. The overall goal is to reduce the number of bytes written to disk. I'd like to use log4j since that's the logging framework that's already in place in the code base.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz the goal is do the compression before the message is actually written to disk rather than compress the logs during the roll

Comment: @tgdavies volume of IO

Comment: A log file is human-readable text, not compressed data. Your question doesn't make sense. You should be compressing the log file *afterwards*, or use a compressing appender. Not compressing individual messages or fields.

Comment: Possibly Flume could do this, it can compress messages: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#FlumeAppender

Comment: @user207421 the goal is to reduce IO load from logging, one way to do that is to write fewer bytes which the compression can help with

Comment: Log4j Is absolutely not an appropriate implementation for what you want. Logs are expected to be human readable. Not sure if there is any log implementation that would work well for this. Write your own files instead.

Comment: The other question is: why are you logging so much data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are approaching the problem from the wrong side: aspects such as compression and file output should be dealt with by the logging backend, not at the level of logging API.

The feature of directly writing to compressed log files have been requested a couple of times, most recently in [LOG4J2-3639](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3639), but was never implemented. It has some inherent problems like the risk of corrupted log files upon application crash.

However, due to the modular nature of Log4j2, you can write your own custom component base on [`FileAppender`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/2.x/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/FileAppender.java)/[`FileManager`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/2.x/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/FileManager.java) that wraps the output stream in a `GZIPOutputStream`.

**Edit:** Alternative solutions might be:

- using a size base [rolling file appender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#rollingfileappender) with a small size limit. The current log file will be uncompressed, but it will rotate often,
- since a concatenation of GZIP files is a valid GZIP file, you can buffer log messages in memory and write them to your file, when the buffer is full.

Comment: How would that work, as the trailer of the gzip file won't be written until the output stream is closed?

Comment: @tgdavies: that's exactly one of the problems of compressing the current file. Due to the format of GZIP, data can be recovered from the unclosed file, but the file will be invalid until the application exits.